# How to disconnect this kind of cable connector?

Tags: connector, cables, disassembly

I'm trying to disassemble a part of my washing machine to clean it, but I'm struggling removing a white plastic cable connector.

Here's a picture of it

[image: White plastic connector]

[image]

I've tried removing it by twisting it, and with plyers, but it deforms when I use too much force.

How can I disconnect it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you have to push on the locking tab at the top wile pulling the connector straight out.  See photo below.  It may be a tight fit, I would use a large flat screwdriver (green arrow) to carefully prize the plug from the socket.

[image]

Comment: I'll try that soon and let you know!

Comment: It doesn't appear to help. The white part that you call a "locking tab" is not moving at all from the main plug.

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: It works! Excellent, thank you!